# umdh.exe -g option

Tags: memory-leaks, umdh

Am using umdh.exe to analyze possible memory leak. I have a question regarding the '-g' option of umdh.exe. I searched the web, and the available documentation says "Logs the heap blocks that are not referenced by the process ("garbage collection")."

Does that mean umdh.exe -g already lists the memory that has leaked (since there are no references to it in the process)?

Please clarify.

Thanks in advance,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Does not indicate failure, only indicates that the memory is no longer in use by the process and can now be collected by garbage collection. This information is used to evaluate how the process behaves, and that their values will depend on how the application operates.

See more info about memory at  [Slides for our All Day PDC 2008 talks on: Performance By Design](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/10/30/slides-for-our-all-day-pdc-2008-talks-on-performance-by-design.aspx)